# What's the purpose of specifying multiple good commits when using `git bisect start`?

Tags: git, git-bisect

I was reading [the official documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) for `git bisect` and found the following description:

> If you know beforehand more than one good commit, you can narrow the bisect space down by specifying all of the good commits immediately after the bad commit when issuing the `bisect start` command:
>
> ```
> $ git bisect start v2.6.20-rc6 v2.6.20-rc4 v2.6.20-rc1 --
>                    # v2.6.20-rc6 is bad
>                    # v2.6.20-rc4 and v2.6.20-rc1 are good
> ```

However, I can't fathom why do we want to specify multiple good commits.

If we have known there is a bug between rc6 and rc4 and tell git that rc6 is bad while rc4 and rc1 are good. Git will still bisect the commits between rc6 and rc4 regardless of knowing rc1 is good, won't it?

### Questions

1. In what case do we want to specify multiple good commits to `git bisect start`?
2. If multiple good commits matters, how does git work when there are multiple good commits specified?

Comment: I could speculate that maybe `git bisect` will just take the most recent good commit and use that.

Comment: It will search between the bad commit and the closest good commit to that bad commit that comes after it. The only thing I can think of right now is that one might not be sure what the order of commits are so you can just specify multiple commits without worrying about order, but that doesn't make much sense for the example in the docs because it's very obvious what the order of those tags should be.

Comment: The mutiple good commits aren't necessarily all on a single linear history. Imagine a bug that might have been introduced by one of several parallel branches. You could specify the last known good commit in each branch, rather than having to specify their common ancestor as the last known good commit.

Comment: (I imagine `git bisect` will cycle through the potential branches while bisecting.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that you only need the latest single good commit if your history is linear. However, multiple good commits could be helpful when it's not linear. Consider:

```
X
|\
G K
| |
F J
|/
E
```

Suppose you know that `X` is bad and `F` is good. At that point any of `G`, `J`, or `K` could be the culprit. If you know both `F` and `J` are good, that narrows it down to either `G` or `K`.

As for your second question about how Git Bisect works when traversing multiple paths, [here's an article](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect-lk2009.html#_bisection_algorithm) which describes it in some detail.